# socks5 authentication state for any user

Tags: authentication, socks

in socks5 server with RFC1929 (user/pass authenticate) how to know request of a authenticate user and tracking it ?
i mean is after primary socks5 calling (client /server) when a authenticate user want to request of socks5 server for get data of resource on web must be user/pass passed again or first calling is ok and socks5 server can be take the state of user for stand to authenticate and once authentication calling is OK  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client authenticates with the socks server only once per connection. The client connects to the socks server and passes it the requested destination address/host, port, and socks authentication credentials, if any.  If the socks server accepts the request then it connects to the destination server and notifies the client of the result. If successful, any subsequent data the client sends to the socks server is sent as-is to the destination server, and vice versa any data the destination server sends is passed as-is to the client, back and forth for the lifetime of the connection.  If the client uses http keep-alives then it can request multiple web resources using a single connection.  Otherwise, it has to reconnect and reauthorize for every new connection it makes.

Comment: for implements RFC1928 & RFC1929 in socks5 server have keep-alive system or it's a optional feature ?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the client and destination server to keep the connection open as long as it is needed. The socks server is just a pass-through proxy. If the client disconnects first, the socks server disconnects with the destination. If the destination disconnects first, the socks server disconnects with the client. There is no keep-alive system in the SOCKS protocol. But the protocol being passed through may have its own keep-alive system (like HTTP does).

Comment: TNQ dear Remy your help is useful